# Missing Artifact ID when adding Evosuite plugin into Maven project in Visual Studio code

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, evosuite

I used the command palette to add the following dependencies into my pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.maven.surefire.modular</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.evosuite.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>evosuite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.evosuite</groupId>
        <artifactId>evosuite-standalone-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.evosuite.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>evosuite-plugins</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.evosuite</groupId>
        <artifactId>evosuite</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>25.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However the pom.xml file gives me an error:

```
Missing artifact org.evosuite.plugins:evosuite-plugins:jar:1.0.6.
```

Would greatly appreciate any inputs because I have been stuck trying to install the Evosuite plugins.

Comment: Have you looked up whether the jar is in the repositories that you have defined?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, how do I check that?

Comment: Did you configure repositories in your `settings.xml`? The artifact you desire is not in MavenCentral, so you need to find a repository that contains it and put this into your `settings.xml`.